# Embedding player when sharing page

Tags: html, embedding

I have a page with embedded youtube player on it.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

When I insert URL of a curtain youtube video page in my FB post, it seems like FB embedding player so I can watch the video right here. I wonder how it works and how I can do the same with my page. In other words: I would like FB (and other social networks, if it's possible) to embed player from my page when someone insert it's URL.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be you get any help

```
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://VEDIO_URL_HEREparse.com"         

    target="_blank">
    <img class="YOUR_FB_CSS_STYLING_CLASS" src="IMAGE_SOURCE_HERE" 
    width="22px" height="22px" alt="Share on Facebook"></a>
```